# Simple jQuery with parrents i quess

Tags: jquery, css

I got stuck i want to move separately the class .inner in the USP! i don't get how this works

How do i solve this problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="usps">
    <div class="dienst">
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="inner">
                <h2>Dakbedekking</h2>
                <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, labore.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="usps">
    <div class="dienst">
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="inner">
                <h2>Dakbedekking</h2>
                <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, labore.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.usps').hover(function(){ 
     $('.inner').toggleClass('up');
     $('.bottom').toggleClass('red');
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target relative elements - in your case I think you want to find the `.inner` and `.bottom` elements within the hovered `usps` element

```
$('.usps').hover(function(){ 
     $(this).find('.inner').toggleClass('up');
     $(this).find('.bottom').toggleClass('red');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P5aL2/)

`this` inside the hover handler will refer to the hovered `usps` element, so you can use that reference to find the `inner` and `bottom` element within the current `usps` element.